# How to keep listview item selected once an item is clicked and change it when another is clicked?

Tags: android, listview

I have tried all the possible solutions out here but none worked for me.
I have a `selector` which checks for the item either being `pressed` or `selected` and `default`.
here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/primary_dark" />
<item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

I have the `Listview` in my `navigationdrawerclass` everything is working fine and i am using `onItemClickListener` but once the item is being clicked it won't stay selected i have looked here and there for solutions but none worked for me.

I am planning to make something like this

**When the item is clicked the text color will change and stay selected but the color is changing as the item is not selected it's not giving the selected color**

[image]

Comment: Starting from API=21 I think this can be totally issued from XML, but for older frameworks you need to take care of that in your adapter (at least for the image).

Comment: can you please either post the code for api=21 orelse if there is any example

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use this [library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer).

There are lots of alternatives to it. You can check it out from android-arsenal by searching navigation drawer.

So, you can easily avoid boilerplate codes.

Good luck there.

Comment: Sorry but i planned on not using any library

Comment: You should call setItemSelected(int position) from your list view in navigation drawer fragment.

Comment: there's no setItemeSelected method